# Install vmware vm into boot instead of virtualized

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, vmware, operating-systems, reinstall

I've been running a virtual machine for a while in vmware.
Luckily now i've got another computer, and there for i was wondering if it's possible get the vm installed in the computer with regular boot and not virtualized.

I'm thinking of a program that takes the vm and a windows iso and combines them together.

Any ideas how i should solve this without a complete reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this is](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/doc/V2P_TechNote.pdf) what you are after . It will provide you with the information needed.[This](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/index.html) may also help it provides links to sample sys-prep files